# Make a trigger that copies new data from table to another table after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I have this code for the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_after` AFTER INSERT ON `hyk50_0001`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO hyk50_0001_copy(Fecha)
    SELECT Fecha FROM hyk50_0001
END;
```

but doesn't work, it says a syntax error but I didn't see it

I'm using Navicat. And **hyk50_0001_copy** it's a identical copy of **hyk50_0001**.
The target is take the new row of **hyk50_0001** and INSERT in **hyk50_0001_copy**

I want put all the database, but if it doesn't work with only a value I can't progress.

Comment: Show the complete definition of the trigger.  One common problem is when `delimiter` is not set correctly.

Comment: I can't see the `delimiter` because the program doesn't show, I only have this code.
And a selector to the event and AFTER or BEFORE.
I'm very new about triggers.

Comment: Sorry, actually I find the code created by the program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a syntax error, but I assume you intend:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_after` AFTER INSERT ON `hyk50_0001`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO hyk50_0001_copy(Fecha)
        VALUES (new.Fecha)
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

That is, you probably want to insert only the row that was just created.